# How to search for a hex or bit pattern in a file in c++?

Tags: c++, search, binaryfiles

I am looking for the most efficient way of reading a data file in binary format and then search for occurrence of a pattern (header) within the file. I have read the file into memory using the cplusplus.com example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream::pos_type size;
char * memblock;

int main () {
  ifstream file ("example.bin", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
  if (file.is_open())
  {
    size = file.tellg();
    memblock = new char [size];
    file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    file.read (memblock, size);
    file.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
  return 0;
}
```

First I am wondering if this is the best way of doing this for my purpose. If yes, I could not find out how to search for a pattern like 0x54 0x51 or it's binary equivalent in the memblock char array.

Comment: Are you looking for a bit or byte pattern? Does `0xA8 0xA2` match? (left shifted by 1)?

Comment: @dahma looks like you're new to Stack Overflow.  Don't forget to mark an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efficient algorithms (in terms of both, theoretical, asymptotical running time and practical efficiency) for your purpose are
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm
and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Just like they operate on readable strings, they work on sequences of bytes. They will also work on sequences of bits (but in this case they usually are not the best options. you should avoid comparing bit by bit and might as well shift your pattern and compare. also your alphabet will contain only 0 and 1 which does not allow the string search algorithms to use their full potential), but regarding your question (and the possible hex representation), I do not think that this is what you want.

However, if you're reading the file from disk, and patterns are not too long, the execution time of your program will vastly be dominated by the time it takes to read from disk. In that case, the naive solution, as posted by Gam Erix, is perfectly fine and much easier to implement.

Another optimization for patterns smaller than a machine word: just interpret the pattern as larger type (uint64_t, for example) and use a single comparison for the whole pattern (you'll have to check bounds when you reach the end of your input sequence)

Answer (score 0):

just read each char and compare it to the first occurence you search for, if it matches, check if the next byte matches the next occurence, when you read a file in binary with fstream it reads the bytes.

Comment: Would that work if he were searching for a bit-pattern shorter than a byte?

Comment: depends on the alignment, you can read bit by bit and store that (bools) or else if it's byte-by-byte alignment then it doesn't matter because you are reading byte by byte anyway so binary comparisions will work too

Comment: Thanks Gam Erix, I was more looking for the algorithms like what b.buchhold suggeted above. Sorry if the question was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the most efficient or even fastest way, and I make no claims to having uber technique, but here's ***a*** way to scan for bit-patterns.

```
//...
file.close();
//...
unsigned int pattern = 0x5451;
unsigned int mask
    = static_cast<unsigned int>(pow(2, 16) - 1) //generate 16-bit mask
;
unsigned int read_buff = static_cast<unsigned char>(memblock[1]);
    read_buff << 8;
    read_buff |= static_cast<unsigned char>(memblock[0]);

//start at index 2 since we already read 2 bytes.
for (ifstream::pos_type i = 2; i < fsize; i += 1) {

    for (char shift_count = 0; shift_count < 8; ++shift_count) {

        //put the third byte into read_buff
        if (shift_count == 0) {
            unsigned int read_byte = static_cast<unsigned char>(memblock[i]);
            read_byte <<= 16;
            read_buff |= read_byte;
        }

        unsigned int work_area = read_buff;
        work_area &= mask;

        if (work_area == pattern) {
            //happy dance
        }

        read_buff >>= 1;
    }
}
```